# Creating app shortcuts to Contact details

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to add app shortcuts to the contact details in my android system, for example in this image i have a shortcut for Revolut.

Note: This is the system contacts, not my app

[image]

Can anyone give me some pointers to what i should be searching? Can't seem to find anything about it in developer website

Comment: Use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on a contact `Uri`, presumably.

Comment: I dind't specify inicially, but this is a screenshot of a contact detail in from my system contact list. this is not a screenshot from my app.

Comment: If you use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on a contact `Uri` for a `startActivity()` call, you will bring up a contact-viewing activity, if one exists on your device. Whether that is from a built-in contacts app (which I guess is a "system contact list") or from a user-installed contacts app is up to the user.

Comment: Ah ok, ill try that out. Thanks